# Package pdftex.def Error: File; What can I do so that LATEX can display the image?

Tags: error-handling, latex, pdflatex

> Latex displays: Error: File `Schreibtisch/BLOCKPRAKTIKUM
> MESSTECHNIK/EE/3c in line 242. What do I need to change so that LATEX
> displays the picture? Unfortunately I am a total noob in LATEX.  Any
> help would be highly appreciated! I really don't know what to do I tried putting it into another folder but it doesn't display the image

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}%müsste das Design sein
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode = fraction, locale = DE}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{esvect}

%Mathe- Makros
    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 
    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}

    \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}


\section{Versuchsaufbau und Durchführung}

\subsection{Fadenstrahlrohr}
Eine gasgefüllte Glaskugel befindet sich in einem Helmholtz-Spulenpaar. Ein Elektronenstrahl wird durch die Lorentzkraft auf eine Kreisbahn gebracht, die durch Anpassung der Spannung an der Spule reguliert werden kann. Anschließend werden die jeweiligen Radien der Kreise gemessen.
\subsection{Milikan-Versuch}
Durch ein Mikroskop beobachtet man das Sinken oder das Steigen der Öltröpfchen in einem Plattenkondensator. Je nachdem wie der Kondensator gepolt ist, werden die Öltröpfchen  entsprechend nach oben oder nach unten beschleunigt. Gemessen wird dann die Zeit, die die Öltröpfchen einmal zum Steigen und dann wieder zum Sinken benötigen. 
\section{Auswertung}

\subsection{Fadenstrahlrohr}
Für 3 Kreisradien mit jeweils 5 Kombinationen aus Beschleunigungsspannnung und Spulenstrom kann man die spezifische Ladung des Elektrons bestimmen. Dazu wird die Spannung  in Abhängigkeit des Stroms im Quadrat betrachtet.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{align*}
         \subfigure[\SI{3}{\centi\metre}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Desktop/BLOCKPRAKTIKUM MESSTECHNIK/EE/3cm.png}}
    \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \subfigure[\SI{4}{\centi\metre}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Desktop/BLOCKPRAKTIKUM MESSTECHNIK/EE/4cm.png}}
    \end{align*}
    \subfigure[\SI{5}{\centi\metre}]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Desktop/BLOCKPRAKTIKUM MESSTECHNIK/EE/5cm.png}} 
    \caption{Diagramme für die Spannung in Abhängigkeit des Stroms im Quadrat für verschiedene Kreisradien}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do with all these math environments inside a figure??? Can you make a sketch of the result you would like?

Comment: If I replace the image with dummy images, remove outdated packages , remove outdated package options (`pdftex`) and add `\begin{document}` the document compiles

Comment: It is just an excerpt of the entire code, I need it for a lab report.

Comment: My goal is just to display the inserted graphic. It has worked before, but I don't know what I clicked or did so that it turned out this way, that I can't insert pictures anymore and LATEX doesn't display the graphics anymore :(

Comment: Can you show your complete  .log file?

Comment: I just removed pdftex. I was able to insert graphics again, but LATEX still doesn't accept .PNG files which I dont know why. I mean it has worked before. Do you have any suggestion how I could rename it or what I can do to be able to insert png files? I would be really thankful!

Comment: png is not supported in `latex`, you need `pdflatex` or similar to use pngs

Comment: Start small with `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}` If this works, start adding things from there.

Comment: Sorry I am a total noob in Latex! Where can I find a .log file? I am using TexMaker on MacOS

Comment: the .log is normally in the same folder then the .tex file

Comment: I tried to send you the log file via copy and paste, but it was too long. Any idea how to insert it into this discussion? :o

Comment: pastebin.com is an easy way to share if it is too long for your question

Answer (score 0):

A couple of remarks about your code:

- the documentclass option `pointlessnumbers` is outdated, use `numbers=noenddot` instead
- the package `scrpage2` is outdated and is even no longer included in current tex distributions. Use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead
- `\clearscrheadfoot` is outdated, use `\clearpairofpagestyles`
- the package option `pdftex` for `graphicx` is not necessary and causes a lot of problems, just remove it, `graphicx` is now grown up can detect itself which mode it needs
- if your tex installation is not totally outdated, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's now the default
- the option `decimalsymbol=comma` for `siunitx` is obsolete, use `output-decimal-marker={,}` instead
- you don't need the `color` package when you also load `xcolor`
- don't load the same package multiple times
- load `hyperref` last (with very few exceptions like `cleveref`)
- instead of reinventing the wheel with `\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}}`, have a look at the `cleveref` package, much more flexible and powerful. For example it won't give an incorrectly large space like your macro
- missing `\begin{document}`
- unrelated to tex, but usually style guides recommend to use words for numbers up to ten, so rather use `drei Kreisradien` instead of `3 Kreisradien`
- your figure is missing floating specifier, e.g. `\begin{figure}[htbp]`
- remove the `align*` environment inside the figure, that's really the most bizarre code I've seen in a very long time
- just use the file name without extension `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}`, latex will automatically use the best available one if there are multiple versions
- avoid special characters like spaces in the path to the image